# Add spaces between each letter of word HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add a little space for styling between each letter of my word, I can achieve this by the following:

```css
.space {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center"><span class="space">S</span><span class="space">p</span><span class="space">a</span><span class="space">c</span><span class="space">e</span><span class="space">s</span></h1>
```

But since there is so much copying and pasting, is there a better / more efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `letter-spacing` CSS

```css
h1 {
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Spaces</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.space {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="space" style="text-align: center">Spaces</h1>
```

or simply you can add `&nbsp;` between letters.

Comment: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet, so that the output can be seen in your answer, and corrected your typo `;nbsp` isn't a thing, and I assume you intended a non-breaking white-space character, which is `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use letter-spacing in css

```
<h1 class="space">Hello</h1>

.space{
 letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```